# How to make a button for the meta tag of light dark mode:

Tags: javascript, html, css, meta-tags

Is it possible to make a button to change the light and dark mode using meta `<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">`, but you can also use a button to change the mode?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a bit of JS code, something like this:

```js
const toggleModeButton = document.querySelector("#toggle-mode-button");

toggleModeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const metaTag = document.querySelector("meta[name=color-scheme]");
  const currentValue = metaTag.getAttribute("content");

  if (currentValue === "light") {
    metaTag.setAttribute("content", "dark");
  } else {
    metaTag.setAttribute("content", "light");
  }
});
```

```html
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
<button id="toggle-mode-button">Toggle Mode</button>
```

This will change the value of the content attribute of the `<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">` tag, which will signal to the browser to change between light and dark mode. You can style your website accordingly by using CSS media queries based on the prefers-color-scheme media feature.

Just be aware this meta tag is not widely supported in all browsers yet, so you probably want to check browser compatibility before using it.

Comment: thanks this actually helped my site out a lot but does it cover all the pages on the website like say I have 4 different pages on my website will it cover it? @emad

Comment: No, the change in the meta tag and the JavaScript code will only affect the page where it is implemented. If you want the change to apply to all pages, you need to use a common header file that is included in all pages, where you can include the meta tag and the JavaScript code. That way, whenever you make a change, it will be automatically reflected on all pages of your website, if you are using use a front-end framework like React or Angular you can avoid duplication of code with reusable components. @michaelbornegx